# How does one query IMDB database for retrieving data for analysis?

Tags: imdb

For example, I want to find the list of actors/actresses that have collaborated with Nicholas Cage the most. DBPEDIA has a extracted data from Wikipedia and put it into a semantic format, what about IMDB? Is there a similar service for such data analysis tasks? I would be interested to hear your answers. I have tried Google but haven't found anything substantial.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [OMDb](http://omdbapi.com/) API

```
<?php
$json=file_get_content("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1285016"); // get i = imdb ID
$info=json_decode($json);
print_r($info);
?>
```

[Sample Output](http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1285016)

The documentation is very clear.

Comment: Nice, does this get me RDF triples? Do they have a SPARQL editor?

Comment: @AliGajani I am sorry, but I don't know either of the things you are asking about. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'll just answer my question since I've discovered an awesome service that has IMDB data extracted into a semantic RDF format with a SPARQL endpoint for querying. This is it.
http://linkedmdb.org/